# How can I query for terms like "@foo" with Postgres full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I would like to be able to query for documents containing `@foo` without matching the naked word `foo`. I'm using the simple dictionary but I notice `@` characters are stripped:

```
SELECT to_tsquery('simple', '@foo');  -- produces 'foo'
```

Is there a way to force Postgres to treat the `@` as significant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the default text parser, in that it splits out the '@' symbol

You can see it here:

```
select 
  ts_lexize('simple', '@foo'), -- {@foo}
  ts_parse('default', '@foo'); -- { (12,@), (1,foo) }
```

lexize is fine and keeps the `@`, but the parser splits it out

You'd need to write your own parser or change the source, which isn't fun if you don't know C!

One work-around would be to change `@foo` to something like `ATSYMBOLfoo` using some wrapper function for `to_tsvector` and `plainto_tsquery`

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. I'm fine with C but this is a hosted database with limited access (and I don't really want a customized postgres). Preprocessing the input data will work though - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use the `CHR` function:

```
SELECT some_text
    FROM testing_stuff t
WHERE t.some_text LIKE '%' || chr(64) || '%' ;
```

this will return any rows where the specified column contains an '@' character. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842929/postgresql-select-query-with-ascii-value-in-where-clause) for another method

Comment: Thanks, but LIKE is not really a substitute for FTS :-(